# Replace "\" in string

Tags: c#

I am struggling how to handle a situation where JSON i am being sent appears to have unescaped characters in it.

I have traced it to some barcodes having a backslash at the beginning.

> \"barcode\":\"\0030172391286\"

JsonSerializer.Deserialize throws an error converting it to an object.

My idea is to use the .Replace function to remove the "\" in front of the barcode.

My attempt at getting the .Replace function is:

```
data.JSON = data.JSON.Replace(@"\""barcode\"":\""\", @"\""barcode\"":\""");
```

but it's not working.

Can anyone suggest how to get the replace function working or suggest a better alternative?

**UPDATE**

It appears that I am incorrect. It might not be the "\" that is the problem.

It might be the "\0" which represents a NUL

So. I have tried:

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
     IgnoreNullValues = true,
};
LM_BegInventory LM_Inventory = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LM_BegInventory>(data.JSON, options);
```

but it still fails with the error:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: '0x00' is invalid within a JSON
>   string. The string should be correctly escaped. Path: $['transaction
>   detail'][5850].barcode | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1457061.
>   ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '0x00' is invalid within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. LineNumber: 0 |
>   BytePositionInLine: 1457061.

Comment: Are you **sure** those characters are **actually** in the string? If you're inspecting the string using the debugger, it will "helpfully" add those in to make it similar to a C# string literal. If you click the small magnifying glass button to inspect the full text you should see it without escaping any characters. Can you do this and verify whether this makes them go away?

Comment: There are no backslashes in that string. That's just how languages like C, C++, Java, Javascript and C# represent characters that couldn't appear in a string without escaping in some form

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen when i hit the magnifying glass it displays barcode":"\030172390050

Comment: Because that's how the debugger displays double quotes *inside* a string literal. This is just a single character. That's not a C# quirk. Most languages use the same escape sequences. You'll find a *lot* of duplicate SO questions about this

Comment: Post the *actual* JSON string, actual code and full exception text (the full string returned by Exception.ToString()). You can get the full exception details if you click on `Copy Exception Details to Clipboard` on the exception popup.

Comment: BTW `\0` is a NUL character. *That* is unexpected. That's definitely invalid as whitespace

Comment: The NUL character is [invalid in JSON](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159). It has to be replaced by an escape sequence (`\u0000`). The code that produced this string has a bug

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parsing the response as a `JObject`?

use NewtonSoft and parse the object as a `JObject`

```
JObject response = JObject.Parse(data.JSON);
```

This should remove all the escape characters and return the object as a `JObject`.

From here you should be able to access the information you need.